# Stored procedure ADO.NET .NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, ado.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building a Web API in ASP.NET Core, I am using stored procedures to be able to handle more complex queries, which with the Entity Framework is too complicated for me, I am using ADO.NET to make this connection.

I have managed to connect to a stored procedure and use the get and post methods, the point is that I don't know how to do it in order to call the other stored procedures and map a route to interact via get or post in the same project. I have only been able to do one, and I don't think it would be more convenient to create a Web API for each function that complies with a stored procedure.

My project is made up of three folders called `Controller`, `Data`, `Models`.

Within `Models` is the `Value` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Models
{
    public class Value
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Data` folder has a class called `ValueRepository`

```
using ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Data
{
    public class ValuesRepository
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public ValuesRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection");
        }

        public async Task<List<Value>> GetAll()
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllValues", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    var response = new List<Value>();
                    await sql.OpenAsync();

                    using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            response.Add(MapToValue(reader));
                        }
                    }

                    return response;
                }
            }
        }

        private Value MapToValue(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            return new Value()
            {
                Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                Value1 = (int)reader["Value1"],
                Value2 = reader["Value2"].ToString()
            };
        }

        public async Task<Value> GetById(int Id)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetValueById", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", Id));
                    Value response = null;
                    await sql.OpenAsync();

                    using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            response = MapToValue(reader);
                        }
                    }

                    return response;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task Insert(Value value)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertValue", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value1", value.Value1));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value2", value.Value2));
                    await sql.OpenAsync();
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task DeleteById(int Id)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteValue", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", Id));
                    await sql.OpenAsync();
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally I have a controller class called `ValuesController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Data;
using ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ValuesRepository _repository;

        public ValuesController(ValuesRepository repository)
        {
            this._repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Value>>> Get()
        {
            return await _repository.GetAll();
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Value>> Get(int id)
        {
            var response = await _repository.GetById(id);
            if (response == null) { return NotFound(); }
            return response;
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task Post([FromBody] Value value)
        {
            await _repository.Insert(value);
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task Delete(int id)
        {
           await _repository.DeleteById(id);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my startup class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ASPNETCore_StoredProcs.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace ASPNETCore_StoredProcs
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<ValuesRepository>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate if you can help me or if it is how I think I should create an API for each procedure that is performed thanks

Comment: what is your ultimate task? to perform the functions, or simply be able to call stored procedures from api (which means using database with api)? Sorry to ask you again if you have already mentioned such details. Asking for confirmation.